# How to change font type, size, and colour in Google form

Tags: google-forms, customization

How can I customise the background, font type&size and the color of a Google form?

Comment: Do you mean a Google Form? There aren't many options for customizing forms, except from finding a theme that is closest to what you want.

Comment: It looks like @VidarS.Ramdal is correct as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 1):

There currently are [no](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/T7HT3jVK6AI) options that allow the users to set font, font size or colour in Google Docs spreadsheet forms. You can only choose amongst the [proposed themes](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/145737?rd=1).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

What You could do is copy all the needed HTML code from the form to your own page and embed it there. Then you have all the control that you want!

Answer (score 0):

This Forms Add-on that embeds Google Forms in websites, helps customize styles, colors and fonts: https://gsuite.google.com/marketplace/app/formfacade/743872305260

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry, but you cannot change the font color.